# timeit on a class function

Tags: python-3.x, python-module, timeit

I am trying to use a timeit() on a function that belongs to a class. The code is given below:
Can anyone please help me out with regards to this matter? Thanks in advance.

```
from random import randrange
import timeit
class Bubbles:
    def __init__(self,nums):
        self._nums = nums
        
    def sorts(self):
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            for j in range(i,len(nums)-1-i):
                if self._nums[j] > self._nums[j+1]:
                    self._nums[j],self._nums[j+1] = self._nums[j+1],self._nums[j]
        return self._nums
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    nums = [randrange(-100,100) for i in range(100)]  ###Small set of numbers
    large_nums = [randrange(-100000,100000) for i in range(100000)]  ##Large set of numbers
    bubble_small = Bubbles(nums)###instance of Bubbles class for small set                             
    bubble_large = Bubbles(large_nums)###instance of Bubbles class for small set       
    print(timeit.timeit("bubble_small.sorts()"))###Bubble sort small set of numbers
    print(timeit.timeit("bubble_large.sorts()"))###Bubble sort large set of numbers
```

Comment: Hi @PranavHosangadi I tried it but it shows `AttributeError: 'Bubbles' object has no attribute 'timeit'

Comment: That's because you tried `"bubble_small.timeit()` (your old code that had a typo). Fix that like you fixed your question

Comment: @PranavHosangadi thanks sorry my bad... hahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `timeit.timeit()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit) runs the code you supply in the `stmt` argument, but it doesn't run in the same scope<sup>not sure this is the right word</sup> as your other code. You can include an argument `setup` that contains code to run *before* the timed code in `stmt`, so that it can import modules, etc. In this statement, you can also get `timeit` to import stuff from your `__main__` code like so:

```
print(timeit.timeit("bubble_small.sorts()", "from __main__ import bubble_small"))
print(timeit.timeit("bubble_large.sorts()", "from __main__ import bubble_large"))
```

Since your code takes quite some time to execute, it might be worth specifying the number of runs you want to time with the `number=100` (or some suitably sized integer) argument to `timeit()`

```
print(timeit.timeit("bubble_small.sorts()", "from __main__ import bubble_small", number=100))
print(timeit.timeit("bubble_large.sorts()", "from __main__ import bubble_large", number=100))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @PranavHosangadi! Appreciate it!